# Python requests irritatingly slow

Tags: python, python-requests

I made a program to find available /id/ on Steam using requests, but it takes a very long time. If anybody knows any way to make requests faster, please inform me of this.

```
w = open("not taken.txt", "a")
f = open("og_users.txt", "r")

def is_steam_customurl_taken(id):
    r = requests.get("https://steamcommunity.com/id/%s" % id)
    if ("The specified profile could not be found.".lower() in r.text.lower()):
        return False
    return True

lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    username = line.strip()
    if is_steam_customurl_taken(username):
        print("%s is taken" % username)
    if not is_steam_customurl_taken(username):
        w.write(username)
        w.write("\n")
        print("%s is not taken" % username)
w.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: you could make this a threaded program, but likely your issue is that Steam is throttling your responses, and not an issue with the `requests` functionality. you could use a library like `timeit` to try to find where the slowdown is.

Comment: If you have Steam IDs, see about obtaining a [Steam Web API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev) key and use a proper API (some sites have measures to detect and block web-scrapers). Their API has a [players endpoint](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUser#GetPlayerSummaries) which allows you to submit 100 IDs per request. If you just have the names tho, try using `xml=1` query param (e.g. https://steamcommunity.com/id/eroticgaben?xml=1) for a much lighter response.

Comment: @David cool find! I had a feeling that existed but did not dig enough into docs to discover the 100 ids per request thing. I'd say post this is an answer as it seems it is ultimately a dramatic game-changer for this task of the OP.

Comment: @alecxe Cool, done.

Answer (score 3):

Your bottlenecks here are, basically, two things:

- network
- the fact that you are processing usernames one by one *synchronously, in a blocking manner*. In other words, you are not processing the next username until you are done with the current.

---

There are a couple of easy wins you can get to improve your current "synchronous" approach:

- instantiate a [`requests.Session()`](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and re-use for your network requests. This should speed things up significantly as you are making requests to the same host:

  > if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase
- do not call `is_steam_customurl_taken()` twice per single row. Do it once and remember the result into a variable:

  ```
  is_taken = is_steam_customurl_taken(username)
  if is_taken:
      print("%s is taken" % username)
  else:
      w.write(username + "\n")
      print("%s is not taken" % username)
  ```

---

As far as making things asynchronous and non-blocking, you can look into packages like [`grequests`](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) or [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) which would allow you to not wait on the network and process more usernames at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Steam IDs, see about obtaining a [Steam Web API key](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth) and use a proper API (some sites have measures to detect and block web-scrapers). Their API has a [players endpoint](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUser#GetPlayerSummaries) which allows you to submit 100 IDs per request.

If you just have the names tho, try using `xml=1` query param (e.g. https://steamcommunity.com/id/eroticgaben?xml=1) for a much lighter response.